# apache server not working after installing zend server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, zend-server

i have apache installed in my redhat 5.3 server machine. and i was trying to install zend server. i installed zend server with install.sh file in directory /var/zend.

in my windows machine after installling zend server community edition i was able to access apache server as well as zend server. 
but in my linux machine localhost displays nothing and localhost:10081 shows zend server.
what can i do to run my localhost?
or
should i seperately install apache?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you installed the tar.gz version of Zend server. If so, you should have a separate apache inside Zend server which listens on port 10088. So you should access it with localhost:10088
This version of Zend server has no intervention in the system so older installations of Apache should behave just the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot some people have this problem too. Even on zend forums the question is still unanswered. when you run zendctl.sh status it tells you that apache is not running (though you have issued the command zendctl.sh start) 
for reference : http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=8828